# How to pack a .exe file with a python script using pyinstaller

Tags: exe, pyinstaller

I wrote a python script that uses an external .exe file for running commands, and I want to pack both .exe and .py files into one .exe file using pyinstaller

At the moment I don't know if pyinstaller supports this? I will be happy to hear if there are alternative ways.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post a minimal working version of your code?

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do it, using the following command:
pyinstaller -y --add-data "C:/Users/Username/Projects/python3/foldername/someExeFile.exe";"."  "C:/Users/Username/Projects/python3/foldername/somePyFile.py"